# Reload table subviews in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a tableView in which i added a slider as a subview. I try this with two methods.

**Method1:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UISlider*  theSlider =  [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(174,12,120,23)] autorelease];
    theSlider.maximumValue=99;
    theSlider.minimumValue=0;
    [cell.contentView addsubview:theSlider];
    return cell;
}
```

**Problem:** If i use this, then if i scroll the table, the slider gets reload & shows me the Minimum Value rather than slide value. So i use second method.

**Method2:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellIdentifier%d",indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
        UISlider* theSlider =  [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(174,12,120,23)] autorelease];
        theSlider.maximumValue=99;
        theSlider.minimumValue=0;
        [cell addSubview:theSlider];
    }  
    return cell;
}
```

**problem:**  I have a next Button in my view.When i try to tab on it, I want to reload all sliders(i.e. set slider values to the minimum). I try to reload table but i did not get the desire result.

Comment: use your method-2 with [cell.contentView addSubview:theSlider]; and follo Vishal's ans. :)

Comment: you need to set value for ur slider. I don't see where you are adding value. You are only setting minimum and maximum value.

Answer (score 2):

As the user changes a slider, you must keep track of its last value. Then in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you must set the slider's value to the last saved value.

Add an instance variable to hold the sliders' values:

```
NSMutableDictionary *_sliderValues; // don't forget to initialize this variable

// Helper method to located the slider in the cell
- (UISlider *)findSlider:(UIView *)view {
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
            return (UISlider *)subview;
        } else {
            UISlider *slider = [self findSlider:subview];
            if (slider) {
                return slider;
            }
    }

    return nil;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SliderCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
        UISlider *theSlider = [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(174,12,120,23)] autorelease];
        theSlider.maximumValue = 99;
        theSlider.minimumValue = 0;
        [theSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:theSlider];
    }

    UISlider *slider = [self findSlider:cell];
    slider.tag = indexPath.row
    slider.value = [_sliderValue[@(slider.tag)] floatValue];

    return cell;
}

// Process changes to a slider
- (void)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)slider {
    NSInteger tag = slider.tag;
    [_sliderValues setObject:@(slider.value) forKey:@(tag)];
}

// called when the Next button is tapped
- (void)nextAction {
    [_sliderValues removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Note: This has not been compiled or run. It may have a typo.

Comment: That's fine. You still need this code to keep track of the slider's values as the table is scrolled. To deal with the reload button you need to clear the saved values, then reload the table.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. The intent of my code is to ensure that if the table is scrolled, the slider values are kept where they were. The slider values should only be reset when the Next button is tapped.

Comment: Did you initialize `_sliderValues`? In the `initXXX` method or `viewDidLoad`, you need `_sliderValues = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`.

Comment: yes, your code is working but it is **not working in `ios5`**

Answer (score 0):

OK from your button call this line it will reload your table view all data that you had added:

```
[[self mytableview] reloadData];
```

Here, mytableview is obj of table view you put your table view object.

Comment: When you use second method then slider display on cell or not?

Comment: but where to add this line?

Comment: below this line: theSlider.minimumValue=0;

Comment: Besides reloading the table (which you probably already knew how to do), you must keep track of each slider's value so you set the value of each slider for each cell.

Comment: but as per second method, when i try to reload table , the code inside `(cell==nil)` is not run.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on next button. Retrive all the sliders inside your tableview and reset it to zero.

```
for (UISlider *but in [self.view.subviews subviews]) // or use [yourtableview subviews]
    { 
        if ([but isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
            [but setValue:0.0];
        }
    }
```